# Application-defined or object-defined error (1004) in VBA, when assigning value from range

Tags: excel, vba

My code gives the error stated in the title and I don't know why, it happens in this line:

```
Time = KNP.Cells(2, LastVans) - KNP.Cells(2, FirstVans)
```

Everything I could but nothing seemed to work...

```
Sub CalculateKPI()

Dim RKPI, KNP, ST As Worksheet
Set RKPI = Sheets("Results KPI")
Set KNP = Sheets("SimNodes")
Set ST = Sheets("SimStartTimes")
Dim LastVans As Long
Dim FirstVans As Long
Dim Time As Long

  RKPI.Cells(1, 2) = "Maximum Crowdedness"
  RKPI.Cells(1, 3) = "Occupation Time"

  '### Einde Stap 2

  For i = 1 To 25
       RKPI.Cells(i + 1, 1) = "Stage" & i

      lastcol = Split(KNP.Cells(i + 2, 
  Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Address, "$")(1)

      TotalMaximumCrowdedness(i) = TotalMaximumCrowdedness(i) + 
  Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(KNP.Range("B" & i + 2 & ":" & lastcol 
& i + 2))

    '## KPI occupationtime per stage
    lastcolnr = KNP.Cells(i + 2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    FirstVans = 0
    LastVans = 0
Dim g As Long
 For g = 1 To 24
    For p = 2 To lastcolnr
        If KNP.Cells(g + 2, p) <> 0 Then
            FirstVans = p
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    Next g

    For p = lastcolnr To 2 Step -1
        If KNP.Cells(, p) <> 0 Then
            LastVans = p
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    Time = KNP.Cells(2, LastVans) - KNP.Cells(2, FirstVans)
    TotalMaximumCrowdedness(i) = TotalMaximumCrowdedness(i) + Time

     lastcolnr = KNP.Cells(i + 2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Next

       Call Costs
         Call KPI3
        Call BusinessStageChange

 End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated, I am pretty new to VBA. If anyone needs the file to help out, I would be pleased to supply it.

Comment: If you step through the code in the debugger to see exactly what's being executed, it should tell you that one of your loops that is setting `LastVans` or `FirstVans` is not running. Learning to use the debugger is one of  the most powerful additions a programmer can make to their toolbox - it's never too soon to start to use it.

Comment: `If KNP.Cells(, p) <> 0 Then` - is that intended as `Cells(1, p)` ?  Might also want to reset FirstVans/LastVans inside each `g` loop iteration, unless you expect values to "carry over" between iterations.

Answer (score 1):

```
Time = KNP.Cells(2, LastVans) - KNP.Cells(2, FirstVans)
```

returns application-defined or object-defined error, because `LastVans` and `FirstVans` are `0`. Thus it is evaluated to `KNP.Cells(2,0)` and the `0` should stand for the column. This is automatically an error, because the first column is 1.

As an advice to avoid this, you may consider the following check:

```
If LastVans > 0 And FirstVans > 0 Then
    Time = KNP.Cells(2, LastVans) - KNP.Cells(2, FirstVans)
Else
    MsgBox "Vans less than 1."
End If
```

Comment: @Scott Cramer. True. Can you please edit the answer, I am away from keyboard.